# Building Android Library Project Using Jsoup Library

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jsoup

I have a android library project(say `SampleLibProject` which generates a jar in bin as `samplelibproject.jar`) which uses Jsoup library to read `href` attribute from `a` tag. 
And In my android App, If I add reference of library using (Project Properties -> Android and browsing library project) App works OK without any issue as I dont require to copy Jsoup in my Android app `libs`.

But If I add `samplelibproject.jar` in `libs` of Android App without Jsoup library I get an Exception that `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup`.

So my question is how can I build SampleLibProject so that there will be no need of adding Jsoup jar in Android App?

As I am not going to distribute sources of LibProject (I will just give `samplelibproject.jar` to clients )  and don't want to force them to include jsoup library in there android project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using android studio unless you are married to eclipse It is one line to import this in the build.gradle for the app "compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'". I am using this to strip html from incoming text into an app.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong or It will just not get added to lib.jar while using Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

The current supported format for distributing android libraries without shipping the entire source code is called AAR. As far as I can tell this only works with Android Studio, but from the format itself it seems that you might be able to generate it manually. Take a look here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Jsoup` sources in my `libproject` solved my problem(Atleast for time being).

@gllowmas,@jucas Thanks for the suggestions though.